# Laravel5.6 (include and yield )

Tags: laravel, include, yield

I'm having trouble with the @include and @yield... I slightly understand the difference but not clearly. so can somebody help me??

1. When should I use @yield?
2. When should I use @include?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916127/whats-the-difference-between-laravels-yield-and-include

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749683/laravel-extends-and-include/39749950#39749950) which explains the difference between the to approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@include** will always render a view

**@yield** will render content based on your route

For example your blade has these directives:

```
//home.blade.php
...
@include('header')
@yield('content')
...


@yield('content') will render a section having name content

@section('content')
  ....
  //this will be rendered at @yield('content')
@endsection
```

include will always render header file but yield will render what you have sent from controller.