# How to fix header and footer of a web if they are in the wrong area

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using a free template for my website, and after I separated the html file into my php file, and called each file (footer,header,and sidebar) from my **admin_layout.blade.php**

```
    @include('layouts.admin_layout.admin_header')

    @include('layouts.admin_layout.admin_sidebar')

    @yield('content')
  
    @include('layouts.admin_layout.admin_footer')
```

After I reload the website, the order should be like this
**header or navbar->content->footer**
but mine has **content** showing up first and after scrolling there is the **header or navbar->footer**

You can check the pictures below

**The content**

[image: content image]

**the header and footer alone below the content**

[image: the header and footer alone below content]

Has anyone ever encountered this kind of issue? Which file needs to be fixed?

Comment: does this help you understand the use of `@yield('content')` ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916127/whats-the-difference-between-laravels-yield-and-include